# Limit panning during pinch to zoom on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have implemented pinch to zoom and panning. Both zoom and pan are working but I would like to limit panning so that the edge of the zoomed image cannot be dragged into the view leaving empty space.

The range of coordinates for different scale factors does not seem to be linear. For example, on an iPad with an image view that is 764x764, at 2x zoom, the range of the transform X coordinate for a full pan is -191 to 191. At 3x, the range is about -254 to 254.

So my question is, how do I calculate the pan limit for any given scale factor?

Here is my code for the gesture recognizers:

```
@interface myVC()
{
  CGPoint ptPanZoom1;
  CGPoint ptPanZoom2;
  CGFloat fltScale;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imgView; // View hosting pan/zoom image
@end

- (IBAction) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
  if ( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan )
  {
    ptPanZoom2 = ptPanZoom1;
    return;
  }

  if ( (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    || (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) )
  {
    CGPoint ptTrans = [sender translationInView:self.imgView];

    ptPanZoom1.x = ptTrans.x + ptPanZoom2.x;
    ptPanZoom1.y = ptTrans.y + ptPanZoom2.y;

    CGAffineTransform trnsFrm1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(ptPanZoom1.x, ptPanZoom1.y);
    CGAffineTransform trnsFrm2 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(fltScale, fltScale);
    self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(trnsFrm1, trnsFrm2);
  }
}

- (IBAction) handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
  if ( (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    || (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    || (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) )
  {
    fltScale *= sender.scale;
    sender.scale = 1.0;

    if ( fltScale <= 1.0 )
    {
      fltScale = 1.0;
      ptPanZoom1.x  = 0.0; // When scale goes to 1, snap position back
      ptPanZoom1.y  = 0.0;
    }
    else if ( fltScale > 6.0 )
    {
      fltScale = 6.0;
    }

    CGAffineTransform trnsFrm1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(ptPanZoom1.x, ptPanZoom1.y);
    CGAffineTransform trnsFrm2 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(fltScale, fltScale);
    self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(trnsFrm1, trnsFrm2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the equation for determining the pan limits:

```
int iMaxPanX = ((self.imgView.bounds.size.width * (fltScale - 1.0)) / fltScale) / 2;
int iMinPanX = -iMaxPanX;
int iMaxPanY = ((self.imgView.bounds.size.height * (fltScale - 1.0)) / fltScale) / 2;
int iMinPanY = -iMaxPanY;
```

In my pan gesture handler I am allowing the pan to go slightly beyond the limits during a changed event so that the user can easily see they have reached the edge.